# How to reset selected item in MDC spinner (AutoCompleteTextview/ ExposedDropdownMenu) with press of a button

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, material-design, spinner

I am working on a simple baseball scoring app where the user picks opposing teams from two Material Design Components dropdown menus. The user keeps track of scores by pressing a button on the corresponding team column. There is a reset button that resets all the scores back to "0". I have figured this part out. What I need help with is, I want this reset button to also reset the spinner back to its default value showing the hint. I'm vaguely familiar with how it works with a regular spinner, but Google has abandoned spinners in favor of AutoCompleteTextview inside of a TextInputLayout in Material Design. I came upon clearListSelection(), but not entirely sure I am implementing it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Better visual of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsNDX.png)

> MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.internal.Experimental;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String[] TEAMS_A = new String[]{
            "Arizona Diamondbacks",
            "Atlanta Braves",
            "Baltimore Orioles",
            "Boston Red Sox",
            "Chicago Cubs",
            "Chicago White Sox",
            "Cincinnati Reds",
            "Cleveland Indians",
            "Colorado Rockies",
            "Detroit Tigers",
            "Miami Marins",
            "Houston Astros",
            "Kansas City Royals",
            "Los Angeles Angels",
            "Los Angeles Dodgers",
            "Milwaukee Brewers",
            "Minnesota Twins",
            "New York Mets",
            "New York Yankess",
            "Oakland Athletics",
            "Philadelphia Phillies",
            "Pittsburgh Pirates",
            "St. Louis Cardinals",
            "San Diego Padres",
            "San Francisco Giants",
            "Seattle Mariners",
            "Tampa Bay Rays",
            "Texas Rangers",
            "Toronto Blue Jays",
            "Washington Nationals"
    };

    private static final String[] TEAMS_B = new String[]{
            "Arizona Diamondbacks",
            "Atlanta Braves",
            "Baltimore Orioles",
            "Boston Red Sox",
            "Chicago Cubs",
            "Chicago White Sox",
            "Cincinnati Reds",
            "Cleveland Indians",
            "Colorado Rockies",
            "Detroit Tigers",
            "Miami Marins",
            "Houston Astros",
            "Kansas City Royals",
            "Los Angeles Angels",
            "Los Angeles Dodgers",
            "Milwaukee Brewers",
            "Minnesota Twins",
            "New York Mets",
            "New York Yankess",
            "Oakland Athletics",
            "Philadelphia Phillies",
            "Pittsburgh Pirates",
            "St. Louis Cardinals",
            "San Diego Padres",
            "San Francisco Giants",
            "Seattle Mariners",
            "Tampa Bay Rays",
            "Texas Rangers",
            "Toronto Blue Jays",
            "Washington Nationals"
    };

    int scoreTeamA = 0;

    int scoreTeamB = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, TEAMS_A);
        final AutoCompleteTextView filledExposedDropdown = findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown_team_a);
        filledExposedDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, TEAMS_B);
        final AutoCompleteTextView filledExposedDropdown2 = findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown_team_b);
        filledExposedDropdown2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        displayForTeamA(0);
        displayForTeamB(0);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 4 points.
     */
    public void addFourForTeamA(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 4;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 3 points.
     */
    public void addThreeForTeamA(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 2 points.
     */
    public void addTwoForTeamA(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 2;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team A by 1 point.
     */
    public void addOneForTeamA(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 1;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 4 points.
     */
    public void addFourForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 4;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 3 points.
     */
    public void addThreeForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 2 points.
     */
    public void addTwoForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 2;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the score for Team B by 1 point.
     */
    public void addOneForTeamB(View v) {
        scoreTeamB = scoreTeamB + 1;
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
    }

    /**
     * Resets the score for both teams back to 0.
     */
    public void resetScore(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = 0;
        scoreTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
        clearListSelection();
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team A.
     */
    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team B.
     */
    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }


    public void clearListSelection() {
        AutoCompleteTextView filledExposedDropdown = findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown_team_a);
        filledExposedDropdown.clearListSelection();
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:override="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/yankees_3_new" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/score_columns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/team_a_column"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/team_a"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:id="@+id/textinputlayout_teamA"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_color">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown_team_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                tools:text="0" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="addFourForTeamA"
                android:text="@string/four_runs" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
                android:text="@string/three_runs" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
                android:text="@string/two_runs" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
                android:text="@string/one_run" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/team_b_column"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/team_b"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="@string/team_b"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_color">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown_team_b"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                tools:text="0" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="addFourForTeamB"
                android:text="@string/four_runs" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="addThreeForTeamB"
                android:text="@string/three_runs" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:onClick="addTwoForTeamB"
                android:text="@string/two_runs" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
                android:text="@string/one_run" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/reset_button"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/score_columns"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="resetScore"
        android:text="@string/reset_button" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/reset_button_teamA"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/reset_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="resetScore"
        android:text="@string/reset_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you solve this somehow? All i want to do is be able to clear it like a text field

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use Spinner.setSelection(int position) method and pass 0 for the first item

Comment: The problem is that this isn't a regular spinner, it's an AutocompleteTextView with the spinner functionality that is part of the new Material Design Components.

Answer (score 0):

When you first start your app, your spinners display "Team A" or "Team B" because you have defined those as string resources and then referenced those in your xml file as android:text="@string/team_b".  The spinners will continue to show Team A or B until you touch them.  Once you touch them, that starts to overwrite the xml definition.

There are multiple ways to solve this, but I would just regenerate the spinners.

In your activity code, use a method called "populateSpinnerA()" and call that method in your onCreate statement rather than hard code the spinners.  Then, when you press the reset button call the populateSpinnerA() method again to completely recreate the spinner from scratch with its original string reference.

Comment: I did as you suggested, I created two methods "populateSpinnerA()" and "populateSpinnerB()" and called them in the onCreate statement. I have called these two methods under resetScore, but the spinners remain unchanged. They are still retaining their selected states. `public void resetScore(View v) {
        scoreTeamA = 0;
        scoreTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
        populateSpinnerA();
        populateSpinnerB();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use -1 , to show the prompt instead of first item :

```
mySpinner.setSelection(-1)
```